# Microsoft Graph - Filtering in SDK C#

Tags: c#, sdk, microsoft-graph-api

Based on another post, I can filter via HTTP requests as follows:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?
$filter=categories/any(a:a+eq+'Red+Category')
```

I am not sure what the a:a stands for here but it works.

I want to replicate this in Microsoft Graph SDK, I am using a query option as per below which does not return any results:

```
       List<QueryOption> options = new List<QueryOption>
                {
                    new QueryOption("$filter", 
                      "categories/any(a:a+eq+'Red+Category'")
                };
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You seem to be executing a search instead of a filter in your c# code.

Try using:

```
var request = graphClient.Users[userId].Events.Request().Filter("categories/any(a:a+eq+'Red+Category')");
var result = await request.GetAsync();
```

Or alternatively:

```
 List<QueryOption> options = new List<QueryOption>
                {
                    new QueryOption("$filter", 
                      "categories/any(a:a+eq+'Red+Category')")
                };
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo on my end - would query option method not work?

Comment: I have tried the alternate approach - didn’t seem to return any results for me - I will try again

Comment: It semms to work for me, when events with matching categories exist. Another reason could be that your event is not in the standard calendar (as "/me/events" only returns events from the default calendar).

Comment: I am trying to write this : https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=categories/any(a:a+eq+'Red+Category') which works in graph explorer i.e. returns messages but returns nothing when i do this:
    
    List<QueryOption> options = new List<QueryOption>
                {
                    new QueryOption("$filter", 
                      "categories/any(a:a+eq+'Red+Category'")
                };


 var messages = graphClient.Me.MailFolders.Inbox.Messages.Request(options).Top(1000).Select("id, subject, isRead, Categories").GetAsync().Result;

Comment: the example code throws a ServiceException (400, Bad request, invalid filter clause); It seems that there is a missing ')' in the filter. Try using "categories/any(a:a+eq+'Red+Category')" instead.

Comment: adding missing ) is also throwing bad request